# How can I include other files in a post in Wyam?

Tags: wyam

I'm trying to include a file with some html in a Wyam post, but I don't really understand how to get this to work.

## config.wyam

I've tried several things in `config.wyam`

First to Add the `Include()` module to `RenderBlogPosts`

```
Pipelines["RenderBlogPosts"].Add(Include());
```

Next to `BlogPosts`

```
Pipelines["BlogPosts"].Add(Include());
```

Then I tried it by adding another pipeline

```
Pipelines.Add("Content",
    ReadFiles("**/*.md"),
    Include(),
    WriteFiles()
);
```

I want to use this to include an html file `test-include.html` in a Markdown file `test.md`. These files are both in the same directory.

## test.md

Here I have used the syntax from https://wyam.io/modules/include

```
---
Title: Test include
Published: 4/6/2019
Tags: [General]
---

# This page should contain the included content

^"test-include.html"
```

## test-include.html

```
<h2>This should show in the post</h2>
```

## Expected result

```
<h1 id="this-page-should-contain-the-included-content">This page should contain the included content</h1>
<h2>This should show in the post</h2>
```

## Actual result

```
<h1 id="this-page-should-contain-the-included-content">This page should contain the included content</h1>
<p>^"test-include.html"</p>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

What version of Wyam are you using? Is sounds like you're also using the blog recipe, is that correct? If on a recent version and using the recipe, [shortcodes](https://wyam.io/shortcodes/) are enabled by default so you shouldn't need to add any extra modules or pipelines. That's the easiest way going forward of including files (the old `Include` module will continue to work, but it needs to be added manually as you've noticed).

Try this:

```
---
Title: Test include
Published: 4/6/2019
Tags: [General]
---

# This page should contain the included content

<?# Include "test-include.html" /?>
```

If the included file contains Markdown syntax, you can even include it *before* the Markdown engine runs with a slight syntax change:

```
---
Title: Test include
Published: 4/6/2019
Tags: [General]
---

# This page should contain the included content

<?! Include "test-include.md" /?>
```

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you so much. Is this mentioned anywhere in the docs. All I found was https://wyam.io/modules/include, which doesn't mention anything about the way you described above. It would have saved me a ton of time.

Comment: @JohanVergeer shortcodes are a new feature that was just added. They're described in general at https://wyam.io/docs/concepts/shortcodes and each one is described more specifically at https://wyam.io/shortcodes/, though explanations of using them in the context of recipes could certainly be improved - we accept PRs! :)